# Let $f(z)$ be a function analytic in a domain containing the segment $[0,1]$ and satisfying $f(z+1)=azf(z)+p(z)$.

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-continuation

> Let $f(z)$ be a function analytic in a domain containing the segment $[0,1]$ and satisfying
>   $$
> f(z+1)=azf(z)+p(z)
> $$
>   in that domain, where $a\in\mathbb{R}$ and $p$ is a polynomial. Show that $f$ can be analytically continued to a domain $\{z\in\mathbb{C}\,:\,|\Im z|<\varepsilon\}$ for some $\varepsilon>0$.

I don't quite know how to work with this. My attempt was to derive this equation until the polynomial disappears, but that gives me the equation (supposing $p$ has degree $(n-1)$)
$$
f^{(n)}(z+1)=naf^{(n-1)}(z)+azf^{(n)}(z),
$$
which I don't find helps much. I can't even think of a way to define this function which would just leave testing analyticity at each integer. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Can you please tell me where this question is from?

Comment: @GeorgSaliba It was a question on the [August 2009 Texas A&M complex analysis qualifying exam](http://www.math.tamu.edu/graduate/phd/quals/ncomplex/a09.pdf). I'm preparing for the upcoming august examination. Why do you ask?

Comment: Just out of curiosity... I was wondering if writing the analytic function $F$ as a Taylor series could help. You can replace it in the equation that $f$ has to satisfy and see where it leads. The Taylor expansion should be around any real number $x_0$ since the domain that we want is $\{z\in\mathbb{C}\,:\,|\Im z|<\varepsilon\}$. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

To begin with, suppose that $f(z)$ has been defined in the square $(-\epsilon,1+\epsilon)\times(\epsilon,\epsilon)$. (By choosing a finite open cover.)

By $f_1(z+1)=azf(z)+p(z)$, we define $f_1(z)$ in $(1-\epsilon,2+\epsilon)\times(\epsilon,\epsilon)$. Let's prove $f_1$ is a direct continuation of $f$. This follows from the fact that they are both analytic and that they agree on $(1-\epsilon,1+\epsilon)\times(-\epsilon,\epsilon)$.

Similarly, we can define $f_2,f_3,\ldots$ and $f_{-1},f_{-2},\ldots$ . Put $f_0=f$.

Finally, define $$F=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}f_n,$$
i.e.
$$F(z)=f_n(z),\forall z\in(n-\epsilon,n+1+\epsilon)\times(-\epsilon,\epsilon).$$
It is clear that $F$ is an analytic continuation of $f$ which satisfies the condition.